# Aitken's $\Delta^2$ Method applied to the Newton's Method

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, convergence-acceleration

Could Aitken's $\Delta^2$ Method be used to accelerate the convergence of the Newton's Method? I simplified $p_n$=$x_n$-$\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2}{x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_n}$ and obtained $p_n$=$x_n-$$\frac{(\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n})^2}{-\frac{f(x_{n+1})}{f'(x_{n+1})}+\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}}$. How can incorporate this sequence to accelerate the convergence of the method?

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method#Derivation_using_Aitken's_delta-squared_process). But notice Newton–Raphson is usually quadratically convergent, whereas $\Delta^2$ is typically used to accelerate linear or alternating logarithmic convergence.